Error in grouping datetime object values using 'groupby' and 'Grouper' in panda dataframe
I am facing anerror while trying to group a column containing dates on the basis of years.
I have converted the column to datetime object and tried groupby and Grouper method, but an facing the following errors:
Column with date/time = earth_time
df['earth_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['earth_time'])

dff=df.groupby(df.earth_time.dt.year)['max_ground_temp(°C)'].mean()
TypeError: Could not convert -20-2-20-1-1-1-5-11-6-8-9-2-3-1-4-5-5-10-30-3-6-6-5-6-8-6-6-8-4-5-3-4-5-8-6-5-3-3-2-1-1-1-3200-1-1-10-1-2-2-4-1000-2-3-100-1-1-50-2-2-10-2-6-2-200-1-2-2-1-3-3-4-2-9-5-7-7-10-100-9-12-9-10-12-7-12-12-8-130-1-11-2Value not available-23-3-2-15-15-14-11-7-16-6-3Value not availableValue not availableValue not available-40-15-16-15-18-11-16Value not availableValue not available to numeric

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y', level='datetime'))
ValueError: The level datetime is not valid


For further context, I have a data table which has the earth_time column containing strings, which I tried converting to date-time to ultimately group them by year. I wish to analyze the dataset year-wise.
What am I missing?

Try to handle invalid inputs when converting datetime
df['earth_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['earth_time'], errors='coerce')


Tried this out, the error persists
